# "TypeError: values.map is not a function" error occured when doing bulk insert in sequelize postgresql

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

### **TypeError: values.map is not a function**

```
TypeError: values.map is not a function
    at ARRAY.\_value (C:\\Users\\node_modules\\sequelize\\lib\\dialects\\postgres\\data-types.js:460:19)
    at ARRAY.\_stringify (C:\\Users\\node_modules\\sequelize\\lib\\dialects\\postgres\\data-types.js:475:29)
    at ARRAY.stringify (C:\\Users\\node_modules\\sequelize\\lib\\data-types.js:24:19)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.escape (C:\\Users\\node_modules\\sequelize\\lib\\dialects\\abstract\\query-generator.js:985:30)
    at C:\\Users\\node_modules\\sequelize\\lib\\dialects\\abstract\\query-generator.js:282:21
    at Array.map (\<anonymous\>)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.bulkInsertQuery (C:\\Users\\node_modules\\sequelize\\lib\\dialects\\abstract\\query-generator.js:274:36)
    at PostgresQueryInterface.bulkInsert (C:\\Users\\node_modules\\sequelize\\lib\\dialects\\abstract\\query-interface.js:834:27)
    at recursiveBulkCreate (C:\\Users\\node_modules\\sequelize\\lib\\model.js:2698:52)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    \::1 - - \[30/Mar/2022:17:02:33 +0000\] "POST /user/proceed/to/checkout HTTP/1.1" 200 57 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0"
```

### This is my controller

```
exports.proceedToCheckout = async (req, res) => {
    const {
        orderList
    } = req.body
    try {
        let allIds = []
        let uuid = orderList[0].userId
        const user = await User.findOne({
            where: { uuid: uuid }
        })
        orderList.forEach(items => {
            allIds.push(items.productId)
            items.userId = user.id
            items.status = 'Order placed.Get you soon!!'
        })
        //The error here
        const order = await Order.bulkCreate(orderList, {
            fields: ['transactionId', 'productName', 'productId', 'totalPrice', 'totalQuantity', 'deliveryAddress', 'userId', 'status'],
            updateOnDuplicate: ['transactionId', 'productName', 'productId', 'totalPrice', 'totalQuantity', 'userId', 'deliveryAddress', 'status']
        })
        if (order) {
            const products = await Products.findAll(
                {
                    where: {
                        id: allIds
                    }
                })
            let updateQuantity = []
            if (products) {
                products.forEach(items => {
                    orderList.forEach(order => {
                        if (items.id == order.productId) {
                            let productList = {
                                id: items.id,
                                productName: items.productName,
                                description: items.description,
                                price: items.price,
                                quantity: parseInt(items.quantity) - parseInt(order.totalQuantity)
                            }
                            updateQuantity.push(productList)
                        }
                    })
                })
                const productUpadate = await Products.bulkCreate(updateQuantity, {
                    fields: ["id", "productName", "description", "price", "quantity", "createdAt", "updatedAt"],
                    updateOnDuplicate: ['id', 'productName', 'description', 'price', 'quantity']
                }) 

                if (productUpadate) {
                    const removeCart = await Cart.destroy({
                        where: {
                            productId: allIds
                        }
                    })
    } catch (err) {
        // console.log("<===========================Error inside Cart proceedTocheckout try catch block========================>", err)
        res.json({
            status: 'FAILED',
            message: 'Remote server unreachable'
        })
    }
}
```

I am new to "node.js". What I am trying to do is to insert bulk insertion into my order table. but I couldn't. the problem is located in the first 'bulk create' method. In the second 'bulk create' method I did it. I tried my level best but I am lost.

Comment: Please add the content of `orderList` and the model definition of `Order`

Comment: Basically it's saying that you're trying to map over something that is not an Array.. If the code causing the problem is in a node_module, then basically you need to ensure that what you are passing into the first bulkCreate method is an Array. If its the first bulkCreate method that is throwing the error, I'd try logging out your orderList variable to make sure its the correct data type that sequelize expects.

Comment: [@Abhikrishnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18634341/abhikrishnan)Did you solve this error if not i can help you

Comment: In my case it was happening because one of the fields was expected to be an Array. Made the changes and everything is good